# Android Studio - Not all nested layouts inside ScrollView's child are showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I need your help!
I have an activity which supposed to be scrollable,
Therefore the ScrollView is the top layout(i hope this is how you call it).

- I used android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView
  -The ScrollView's child is a LinearLayout with a couple of more nested LinearLayouts.

Now *my problem is* that on the preview screen(Design) i see my layout fine
but when i run the app on an Emulator,i only see half of my layout (until the first nested LinearLayout) and as a collateral damage, the scrollview isn't scrollable.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Design Screen Image:
**[At the preview screen it looks good]**

[image]

Emulator Screen Image:
**[As you can see ,only half of the scrollview's content is showing ]**

[image]

**Updated** layout file:(still showing only half of the layout at runtime)
Added:
- tools:context=
- ScrollView changed from layout_height="wrap_content" to 
   layout_height="match_parent"

- Removed all instances of weight="1" from all nested LinearLayouts.
  AddParkingActivity.xml:

  xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

  ```
      <ScrollView  
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"  
      android:layout_height="match_parent"  
      android:layout_weight="1"  
      android:background="#FFA3D2E9"  
      android:clickable="true"  
      android:clipToPadding="false"  
      android:fillViewport="true"  
      android:focusable="true"  
      android:layoutDirection="rtl">  


         <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layoutDirection="rtl"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:textDirection="rtl">


          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_tv_title"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_margin="20dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
              android:fontFamily="cursive"
              android:text="הוספת חנייה חדשה למסד הנתונים"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              android:textSize="24sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:typeface="monospace" />

          <EditText

              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_Name"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="שם החניון"
              android:inputType="textPersonName"
              android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
              android:textColor="#ffff"
              android:textDirection="rtl"
              android:textSize="18sp" />

          <EditText

              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_area"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="אזור מפורט"
              android:inputType="textPersonName"
              android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
              android:textColor="#ffff"
              android:textDirection="rtl"
              android:textSize="18sp" />

          <Spinner
              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_subAreaSpinner"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
              android:textColor="#ffff"
              android:textDirection="rtl"
              android:textSize="18sp" />

          <View
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="2dip"
              android:background="#FF909090" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_radioG1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:background="#FFA3D2E9"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:textDirection="rtl">


              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_crewAcc_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/radioLeft"
                  android:text="לינה לצוות"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_water_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="מים"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_showers_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="מקלחות"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_accessibility_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="נגישות"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />


          </LinearLayout>

          <View
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="2dip"
              android:background="#FF909090" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_radioG2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:background="#FFA3D2E9"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:textDirection="rtl">


              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_fence_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/radioLeft"
                  android:text="גדר"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_toilets_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="שירותים"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_cookingPos_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="עמדות בישול"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_equipmentToBor_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="ציוד להשאלה"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />


          </LinearLayout>

          <View
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="2dip"
              android:background="#FF909090" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_radioG3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:background="#FFA3D2E9"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:textDirection="rtl">


              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_electricity_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/radioLeft"
                  android:text="חשמל ותאורה"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_securityServ_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="שירותי אבטחה"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />

              <RadioButton
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_medicalServ_radio"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                  android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                  android:text="שירותי רפואה"
                  android:textColor="#000"
                  android:textDirection="rtl" />


          </LinearLayout>

          <View
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="2dip"
              android:background="#FF909090" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_radioG5"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:background="#FFA3D2E9"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:textDirection="rtl">


              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_buttonMarkAll"
                  android:layout_width="49dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                  android:onClick="onMarkAllClick"
                  android:text="סמן הכל" />

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_buttonUNMarkAll"
                  android:layout_width="50dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                  android:onClick="onUNMarkAllClick"
                  android:text="אפס כפתורים" />


          </LinearLayout>

          <EditText

              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_securityOrganization"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="@string/securityOrg"
              android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
              android:textColor="#ffff"
              android:textDirection="rtl"
              android:textSize="18sp" />

          <EditText

              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_notes"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="הערות נוספות"
              android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
              android:textColor="#ffff"
              android:textDirection="rtl"
              android:textSize="18sp" />


          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_radioG6"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:background="#FFA3D2E9"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:textDirection="rtl">


              <EditText

                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_googleMapsY"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                  android:ems="10"
                  android:hint="ערך עשרוני שני \n בגוגל מפות"
                  android:inputType="number"
                  android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                  android:paddingStart="10dp"
                  android:textColor="#ffff"
                  android:textDirection="rtl"
                  android:textSize="12sp" />

              <EditText

                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_googleMapsX"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                  android:ems="10"
                  android:hint="ערך עשרוני ראשון \n בגוגל מפות"
                  android:inputType="number"
                  android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                  android:paddingStart="10dp"
                  android:textColor="#ffff"
                  android:textDirection="rtl"

                  android:textSize="12sp" />


          </LinearLayout>


          <EditText

              android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_type"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="סוג חניון או בעלות"
              android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
              android:textColor="#ffff"
              android:textDirection="rtl"
              android:textSize="18sp" />


          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_radioG4"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:background="#FFA3D2E9"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:textDirection="rtl">


              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/addParkingActivity_buttonADD_PARKING"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                  android:onClick="onAddParkingPressed"
                  android:text=" הוסף חנייה"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                  android:textSize="16sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />


          </LinearLayout>

          <View
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp" />
      </LinearLayout>


  </ScrollView>
  ```

Comment: is there any error message in debug log? have you tried to uninstall and re-install application from android studio?

Comment: There are no errors in the the Logcat. I've re-installed the app but nothing has changed unfortunately. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you are missing the 'android' namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Should go in your ScrollView.

Second, I would make the ScrollView take up the entire screen so change it's height from:

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to "match_parent":

```
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Also, remove the `layout_weight` from all the elements that should be vertically stacked. I see these: `ll_radioG1`, `ll_radioG2`, `ll_radioG3`, `ll_radioG5`, `ll_radioG6`, `ll_radioG4`

You're basically asking those widgets to expand infinitely, because in a ScrollView you have unbounded vertical space.

Comment: You are right, the layout_height should be "match_parent".I changed it but i still get the same result.Thanks for the correction though.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me solve my problem Sir, i have 2 questions about your last edit:1) "remove the layout_weight from all the elements that should be vertically stacked" - by removing do you mean change to layout_weight ="wrap_content"   ?                               2)All these LinearLayouts you mentioned (ll_radioG1, ll_radioG2, ll_radioG3, ll_radioG5, ll_radioG6, ll_radioG4) are set to **android:orientation="horizontal"** so i dont see the problem with them. Thanks a lot for helping Sir.

Comment: The `layout_weight` means take up all available space in the parent, while your orientation="horizontal" is for it's children.

Comment: I removed all the android:layout_weight="1" instances ,but i still see only half of my layout when i run the app.

Comment: Update your post with the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is really weird but i fixed the issue by coping the xml code to another layout file.  I guess the first xml file got corrupted after doing a lot of changes and importing a lot of libraries.  Thank you @DataDino for the help!